# A paragraph of KMP search method in Sedgewieck's book

Tags: string, algorithm, search

I'm reading the KMP search method by Prof. Sedgewick and Wayne. There is a paragraph describing the method as follows,

Once we have computed
the dfa[][] array, we have the substring search
method at the top of the next page: when i and
j point to mismatching characters (testing for a
pattern match beginning at position i-j+1 in the text string), then the next possible
position for a pattern match is beginning at position i-dfa[txt.charAt(i)][j].But
by construction, the first dfa[txt.charAt(i)][j] characters at that position match
the first dfa[txt.charAt(i)][j] characters of the pattern, so there is no need to back
up the i pointer: we can simply set j to dfa[txt.charAt(i)][j] and increment i,
which is precisely what we do when i and j point to matching characters.

I don't understand why it says "when i and
j point to mismatching characters (testing for a
pattern match beginning at position i-j+1 in the text string)". As in the attached picture (also from the textbook), if the text is "ABABAC", and the patter is "BBBBBB", then it mismatches at i = j = 0, which means we are testing for a pattern match beging at 0 position in the text string. How could it be testing for a pattern match beginning at position i-j+1 = 1 in the text string?

My second question is "when i and j point to mismatching characters(...), then the next possible position for a pattern match is beginning at position i-dfa[txt.charAt(i)][j]". For the same example, when i=j=0, the mismatch happens, then i-dfa[txt.charAt(i)][j]=0. According to the text, then the next possible position for a pattern match is beginning at position i-dfa[txt.charAt(i)][j]=0. Doesn't this mean i will stay at 0 forever? Then the search doesn't continue at all?

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

After rethinking about the paragraph, I think the Professors made a mistake here. It should be

when i and j point to mismatching characters (testing for a pattern match beginning at position i-j in the text string), then the next possible position for a pattern match is beginning at position i-dfa[txt.charAt(i)][j]+1.

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstood what he was saying.

You test for a mismatch at position i-j+1 after you found a mismatch between txt.charAt(i+j) and pat.charAt(j). You don't need to look at the first character of txt.substring(i, i + j + 1) because you already know that it will lead you to a mismatch which you just found.

As for your second question, when you back up the i pointer to i-dfa[txt.charAt(i)][j], in your example, it's not going to be in there forever, because you're forgetting that we are in a loop, that increments i by 1 with every iteration, hence why we will be going through the string "ABABAC" until we find the first "B".